# Sort List of date database at Android Studio with cursor loader

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am having trouble sort date database at android studio..
i have try at SQlite  : `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE date BETWEEN "2017-07-01" AND "2017-07-31";`
it's work at SQLite, i have a problem at android  studio, i have try make the `selectionArgs= {BETWEEN "2017-07-01" AND "2017-07-31"}`
 but it didnt work.
What is the input for that SQLite statement at android studio and i use cursor loader..

```
String selection = ?
String [] selectionArgs= ?
```

and also how to sort by ASC?

Comment: wrt sorting: `String sortOder = "date ASC";`, It takes any sqlite `ORDER BY` clause without the `ORDER BY` keyword. Even complex ones like `"date, name, address1 ASC, address2  COLLATE LOCALIZED DESC"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for

```
String selection = "date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
String [] selectionArgs = new String[] { "2017-07-01", "2017-07-31" };
```

And you should be able to order the result using the version of `SQLiteDatabase::query` that takes an `orderBy` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Let the database sort the results.
Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE date BETWEEN "2017-07-01" AND "2017-07-31"
order by date;
```